# Background service does not run permanently using Android sensors to provide mock location data

Tags: android, service, background, background-process, sensors

My app provides mock location data while running in the background, using sensors like accelerometer etc to detect steps of the user. 
My background service only runs for a minute or two before it stops. I am not sure if I implemented the background service correctly for Android O, as there are new requirements and restrictions.

On the Main Activity I start the service with these lines:

```
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
        BackgroundIntentService.enqueueWork(this, BackgroundIntentService.class, 6767, serviceIntent);
    // Static variable to check in the JobIntentService if it should still run.
    Config.backgroundServiceActive = true;
    //Then I close the Mainactivity and the Service runs as expected in the background.
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(startMain);
```

My BackgroundIntentService is a JobIntentService:

```
public class BackgroundIntentService extends JobIntentService {

@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {

   //here I create a new object which handles the sensors
   //I also pass over the context of this JobIntentService

   //This writes in the log just to check if the service is still running.
    while (Config.backgroundServiceActive){
        try{
            Log.i("BackgroundService", "ICH AM AWAKE ");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

In my Manifest I have declared the service:

```
        <service
        android:name=".tools.BackgroundIntentService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

When my MainActivity closes and my service runs in the background doing its work and also writing in the log, everything looks fine. But after 1-2mins the service just stops. What did I do wrong? 
Please make sure your reponse considers the latest changes in Android O.

I used this, which was a bit confusing: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service#java
And this: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/JobIntentService

Comment: If you look at the documentation it has a callback `JobIntentService::onStopCurrentWork` - "This will be called if the JobScheduler has decided to stop this job. The job for this service does not have any constraints specified, so this will only generally happen if the service exceeds the job's maximum execution time." source : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html#onStopCurrentWork() - this time is not documented, but this is what is happening and you can easily confirm by overriding this method and adding logging.

Comment: After exactly 1 minute onHandleWork is basically not called anymore. JobIntentService::onStopCurrentWork is not called and no other method I overwrote.

Comment: Services in Android cannot run indefinitely.  If your design requires that, you need to rethink what you're trying to do and come up with a new way to do it.

Comment: So it is not my implementation then. How do similar apps do that? For example step trackers who track steps in the background over hours?

Comment: According to the definition on the google documentation my app should probably run as ForegroundService. As my app provides mock location data to other apps, it should fall in this category: "Another foreground app is connected to the app, either by binding to one of its services or by making use of one of its content providers." https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services